Gauge transformation with harmonic one-form
The electromagnetic four-potential $A^{\mu}$ is not uniquely determined by the physical situation. We have the equation $$\partial^{\mu}A^{\nu}-\partial^{\nu}A^{\mu}=F^{\mu\nu}.$$
Here $F^{\nu\mu}$ is determined by the $E$ and $B$ fields, so $F$ is uniquely fixed by the physical situation. To move between different versions of $A^{\mu}$ that correspond to the same $E$ and $B$ fields, we can make a gauge transformation:
$$A^{\mu}\rightarrow A^{\mu}+X^{\mu}.$$ Now the condition on $X^{\mu}$ is that
$$\partial^{\mu}X^{\nu}-\partial^{\nu}X^{\mu}=0.$$
I saw on Wikipedia that the gauge freedom consists of two parts: we can add an exact form and a harmonic form.
The exact form would be $$X^{\mu}=\partial^{\mu}f$$
for a scalar field $f$. But I don't understand what a harmonic form is (in the context of Minkowski space). What kind of gauge transformation would that give us?

You can add any vector field whose curl is zero (any one-form whose differential is zero). If you are working in a simply connected domain (no holes) then these vector fields can only be the gradients of scalar functions (exact one-forms), because no other vector fields have zero curl. However, if you are working in a non-simply-connected domain, there could be vector fields that are not gradients (not exact), but have zero curl (harmonic forms). One example in 2D would be the surface of a torus with a constant vector field pointing around the curve of the torus. See, e.g., the figures here.
As a side-note, the question of what forms can be closed but not exact (harmonic) on a manifold is answered by the de Rahm cohomology of that manifold.

Could you provide a source/motivation why there are no harmonic forms in a simply connected domain?

I found the Poincaré lemma, which states that on a contractible space, every closed form is exact.

In this math SE question I ask whether Minkowski space is contractible: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4892388/is-minkowski-space-contractible

See https://planetmath.org/closeddifferentialformsonasimplyconnecteddomain. But the proof is basically the same proof that a curl+free field has a potential.

I added to the Wikipedia article [see link in the question] that the harmonic term vanishes in Minkowski space.

Harmonic forms are solutions of the Laplace equation
$$
(\delta d +d\delta)\psi=0.
$$
In infinite flat space a harmonic form would be a $C_mdx^\mu$, where the $C_\mu$ are numerically  constant. With, for example, periodic boundary conditions  constants cannot be written as a gradient $C_\mu = \partial_\mu f$ of a function $f$ which is  periodic, so they are indeed something in addition to the usual gradient.
